# How do i extract a Date out of a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, regex

I can't seems to find out how to extract the date from a string in a column. e.g:

```
2015-03-30T04:04:26+0200 -> 30.3.2015
```

I tried to look for a regex query but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You may want to store it as a `DateTime` instead of a string, then things are a lot easier.

Comment: Which dbms? (Both date/time and regexp are too often product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Pure SQL Solution

#### i.e. MySQL

since you are asking SQL here, how about:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE("2015-03-30T04:04:26+0200"),"%d.%m.%Y")
```

which returns

```
30.03.2015
```

#### i.e. Oracle

If you want to run this query on Oracle, then you will have to adapt the query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2015-03-30T04:04:26+0200', 1, 10),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD.MM.YYYY') myDate FROM dual
```

#### i.e. PostgreSQL

Also here a few differences in the query. Actually quite the same as Oracle. I cheated here and moved the `0200` at the end into `US` which is actually for microseconds, but gives us a valid parse format string without having to use `SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2015-03-30T04:04:26+0200','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS+US'),'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

#### i.e. SQLite

Now here a completely different function. SQLite uses `strftime()` to format dates. But here i use `substr()` again:

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%d.%m.%Y',DATE(SUBSTR('2015-03-30T04:04:26+0200',1,10)))
```

Now i could go on with MS SQL Server and more but i reckon with these alternatives you should find a way of translating the problem to your DBMS SQL syntax.

### Option 2: Pure RegEx Solution

#### PCRE RegEx (Python, PHP, etc.)

or if you want to use plain regex:

```
(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)T.*
```

which you substitute with

```
\3.\2.\1
```

This you can play around with here:
[RegEx Fiddle Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/tU4mQ5/1)

#### Javascript, Java, etc.

Depending on your programming language, you might need to change your RegEx to:

```
([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)T.*
```

and your replacement string to

```
$3.$2.$1f
```

Comment: Can't you inform which product this is for?

Comment: since there where no parameters in the question concerning database or programming language, i just tested MySQL for the SQL query and the RegEx is PCRE and should work in PHP, - i will update answer

Comment: @JacobSharir gave three more DB samples for Oracle, PostreSQL and SQLite. If this entry helped, please mark question as answered, so it will be found easier

Comment: @JacobSharir "*which runs SQL*" doesn't tell us anything about the DBMS that you are using. "SQL" is just a query language and is used by all relational databases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is why i gave jacob four different SQL samples, which show, that the queries are similar, but very different depending on DBMS. Since he mentioned "BI Dashboard" i figured he is using an Oracle based system :)

Comment: Sorry, that comment was meant for Jacob.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work in a lot of databases:

```
select cast(left(col, 10) as date)
```